# Merging multiple columns and filling in NA answers

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning, na

I have a dataset with over 14000 observations and 43 variables. The data was collected across 11 countries and for two of the questions, participants were asked different variations of the same question based on the country they were in, meaning that for 2 variables I actually have 22 columns. Basically, here is an example of what the df looks like:

```
df <- data-frame(country = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), Q1_UK = c(1, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q1_FR = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA), Q1_ES = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 1), Q2_UK = c(1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Q2_FR = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA), Q2_ES = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 1))


   country  Q1_UK Q1_FR Q1_ES Q2_UK Q2_FR Q2_ES
1       1       1    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
2       1       2    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
3       1       2    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
4       2      NA     2    NA    NA     1    NA
5       2      NA     1    NA    NA     2    NA
6       2      NA     2    NA    NA     2    NA
7       3      NA    NA     2    NA    NA     1
8       3      NA    NA     2    NA    NA     2
9       3      NA    NA     1    NA    NA     1
```

and so on...

I want to have 2 single variables containing all responses for different countries - with an end result like this:

```
  country Q1 Q2
1       1  1  1
2       1  2  1
3       1  2  2  
4       2  2  1 
5       2  1  2 
6       2  2  2 
7       3  2  1 
8       3  2  2
9       3  1  1
```

I was thinking that rotating the dataframe, using fill(), and then rotating again might work but I was not too sure how to go about it and how to make sure that the answers are only filled in by question and not across variables. I am really new to R and I am exhausted so I might just be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with `pivot_longer`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -country, names_to = c(".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_.*", values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

-output

```
 A tibble: 9 × 3
  country    Q1    Q2
    <int> <int> <int>
1       1     1     1
2       1     2     1
3       1     2     2
4       2     2     1
5       2     1     2
6       2     2     2
7       3     2     1
8       3     2     2
9       3     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does not work when I am doing it on the actual dataframe (what I put in my question is just an example as the df is quite big). Do I need to change the names_pattern() argument? I don't really understand how it works even after looking it up.

Comment: @ouroboro  It is based on the column name pattern that you showed as example here.  If your original have different pattern, it may needs change

Answer (score 0):

**1. approach**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  unite(newcol, -country, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  separate(newcol, into = LETTERS[1:ncol(df)]) %>% 
  select(where(function(x) any(!is.na(x))))

 country A B
1       1 1 1
2       1 2 1
3       1 2 2
4       2 2 1
5       2 1 2
6       2 2 2
7       3 2 1
8       3 2 2
9       3 1 1
Warning message:
Expected 7 pieces. Missing pieces filled with
`NA` in 9 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].
```

**2. approach**

Here is one that is modified using `names_sep`. If we use `names_sep` we have to add name of column to `names_to` because  `names_sep` can't be used with a
length 1 `names_to`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df, cols = -country, 
             names_to = c(".value", "name"),
             names_sep = "_",
             values_drop_na = TRUE)


  country name     Q1    Q2
    <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1 UK        1     1
2       1 UK        2     1
3       1 UK        2     2
4       2 FR        2     1
5       2 FR        1     2
6       2 FR        2     2
7       3 ES        2     1
8       3 ES        2     2
9       3 ES        1     1
```